# Relocating Win8 programs downloaded from the app store

Tags: windows-8

By default it appears Windows 8 installs app from the MS App Store to the C drive, is it possible and if so how to install them to a different drive?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible.  Its just not supported and can cause all sorts of problems including a situation where the applications will just simply crash.  How you would actually do this has been asked before.  I just couldn't find the question after only 5 minutes of looking.

Comment: Since I knew this question has been asked before with an answer on ow to actually do this, I just wasn't able to find it, I went ahead and found this guide instead: http://techtrickz.com/how-to/save-ssd-space-by-installing-metro-apps-on-another-drive-how-to/. I refuse to post it as an answer because I don't agree with hacks like this.

Comment: Thanks for looking and the link, I will look into it to see what is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[How to Change Metro Apps Default Installation Location in Windows 8?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-change-metro-apps-default-installation-location-in-windows-8/)

> 1. Press "WIN+R" key combination to launch RUN dialog box then type regedit and press Enter. It'll open Registry Editor.
> 2. Now go to following key:
>
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx
> 3. In right-side pane, you'll see a String PackageRoot containing "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" as its value.

[image]

> 4. You just need to change its value to your desired drive or folder. But
>      Windows will not allow you to modify its value because you don't have
>      required permissions.
>
> To change the value, you'll need to take ownership of "Appx" key.
>
> 5. After taking ownership and assigning full control to your user account, double-click on PackageRoot and change its value to your
>      custom location such as E:\WindowsApps or any other location.

[image]

> That's it. Close Registry Editor and restart your system and now whenever you'll install a new app from Store, it'll be installed in the new location instead of default installation location.

Comment: Thanks, will try this weekend and report back if it works or not. Marking accepted till then